# Removing Characters within a string-Java

Tags: java, string, char

I keep getting an error with removing a character from within a string. I have tried everything that i could find on this site and nothing has worked. This is NOT a help post. Rather maybe an answer that explains why this shows up and how to fix it in case someone else encounters this issue. Without further a due, here is my code:

```
public JTextField Clean()
{
    String Cleaner = TopField.getText();
    Cleaner=Cleaner.toLowerCase();
    int Length = Cleaner.length();
    StringBuilder Combiner = new StringBuilder(Cleaner);
    for (int x=0;x+1<Length;x++)
    {
       char c = Cleaner.charAt(x);
       char c1 = Cleaner.charAt(x+1);
       if(c==' ' && c1==' ')
        {
            Combiner.deleteCharAt(x);
            Cleaner=Combiner.toString();
        }
       if(c!='a' && c=='b' && c!='c' && c!='d' && c!='f' && c!='g' && c!='h' && c!='i' && c!='j' && c!='k' && c!='l' && c!='m' && c!='n' && c!='o' && c!='p' && c!='q' && c!='r' && c!='s' && c!='t' && c!='u' && c!='v' && c!='w' && c!='x' && c!='y' && c!='z' && c!=' ')
        {Combiner.deleteCharAt(x);
         Cleaner=Combiner.toString();}
       }     

      TopField.setText(Cleaner); 
      return TopField;               
}
```

I receive an error that states that My value is out of bounds by the length of the string that i input. Please note that this is a method inside a class that i created that removes any character that is not an alphabet or space.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The horror! Lear how character encoding a work. That `if` block IS JUST TOO PAINFUL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things that pop out at me.

- Your basing your loop on a fixed value (`Length`), but where the actual length of the `String` can decrease...
- You are potentially removing 2 characters per loop (there are two `deleteCharAt` calls)
- The loop doesn't take into account the shrinking size of the `String`. For example. `x == 1`, you remove the character at `x`, you increment `x` by 1 (`x == 2`), effectively skipping a character (the character at position 2 is now at position 1
- Your `if` statement is unnecessarily long.  In fact, depending on your needs, you could use `Character.isDigit` or `Character.isLetter` and `Character.isWhiteSpace`

---

```
String Cleaner = TopField.getText();
Cleaner = Cleaner.toLowerCase();
StringBuilder Combiner = new StringBuilder(Cleaner);
int x =0;
while (x < Combiner.length()) {
    char c = Combiner.charAt(x);
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c == ' ') {
        Combiner.deleteCharAt(x);
    } else {
        x++;
    }
}
```

From the looks of your code, you appear to wanting to filter a `JTextField` so it will only allow numeric values.  It would be much better to use something like a `JSpinner`, `JFormattedTextField` or `DocumentFilter` and ensure the correctness of the data as it's entered...IMHO

Answer (score 4):

As you remove characters, `Cleaner` becomes shorter, so you're likely to reach a point where `x` is too large.

I would suggest a different approach using regular expressions:

```
string cleaned = TopField.getText().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z ]", "");
```

Comment: This indeed can be the problem, how would i go about fixing it?

Comment: I decremented the length and the error is gone! However, it does not remove the character, it doesnt do anything at all.

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie I've already up-voted you answer, but if I could, I would again for the regexp! +2

Answer (score 0):

I used a isDigit() function and found the output as incorrect. Look at the code I tested and found problem with the output. Any one explain.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String temp="you got 211111 out of 211111?";
    StringBuilder cleaner=new StringBuilder(temp);
    for(int i=0;i<cleaner.length();i++)
    {
        char c=cleaner.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isDigit(c))
        {
            cleaner.deleteCharAt(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cleaner);
```

I am getting output as : you got 111 out of 111?

it is not removing some digits.

Also found that no function called replaceAll() is there in Java.

Comment: Just use madprogrammers example O.O